# FileUpload - what is the type of HTTP request

Tags: http, httpwebrequest

can we able to upload a file using HTTP GET or POST requet in HTML FORM tag.

## update

what is the behaviour if i use GET in form tag.

Comment: @pekka i am using JAVA server side page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a POST request and set the form's `enctype` to `multipart/form-data`

**Re your update:** You need POST to upload a file, otherwise the form will be posted but the file won't come along.

GET is limited to a few kilobytes in maximum length, and `multipart/form-data` will work only with the POST method.

Comment: you beat me to it, i'll just delete mine